# Improve/smooth 3D-plot of DEM(Digital elevation model) terrain surface from GeoTIFF using python and matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

the first results of my DEM plotting with matplotlib are working, but are RAM consuming and do not look very pretty.

Since Im just a beginner I dont know how to improve the result further, so it will look more like a terrain surface (in terms of elevations).

What I did so far:

1. gathering DEM geotiff data. Plotting it in 2d is simple and the result will look like that:
   [image]
2. secondly i used that geotiff to squeez it into some plotting code samples i gathered online (especially from here: https://jackmckew.dev/3d-terrain-in-python.html )
   [image]

As seen, the 3d-plot is  on square basis and the surface is very "spiky". Id like to keep it in real proportions (geo-projections) and have it less spiky.
I already tried to lower the Z-ratio, but that does not change the end-result. The spiked are still there. I got no problems with smoothing the data and lose/change the data a bit.

The code so far:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

source_file_dem = 'path_to_the_tif_file'


dem = gdal.Open(source_file_dem)
gt  = dem.GetGeoTransform()
dem_array = dem.ReadAsArray()

lin_x = np.linspace(0,1,dem_array.shape[0],endpoint=False)
lin_y = np.linspace(0,1,dem_array.shape[1],endpoint=False)
y,x = np.meshgrid(lin_y,lin_x)
z = dem_array

# Creating figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,cmap='terrain', edgecolor='none')
fig.colorbar(surf, ax=ax, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
ax.set_title('Surface plot')
plt.xticks([])  # disabling xticks by Setting xticks to an empty list
plt.yticks([])  # disabling yticks by setting yticks to an empty list

# show plot
plt.show()
```

TIF files can be obtained here:
https://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/download

or you can just download a randomly picked tile in the US:
https://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/wp-content/uploads/files/srtm_5x5/TIFF/srtm_15_06.zip

For all who want to try that out:
the python gdal wheels can be found here:
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

Does anyone know where to look or could help out to reach a better looking result?
Thanks

UPDATE:
after some further research and hints from simon I got some results.

The current state result looks like that:
[image]

The code for the plot + an addition class for drawing arrows in 3D. Feel free to use it or even improve it. Id be glad to hear about improvements:

Plot:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage
from PIL import Image
from arrows3dplot import * # python_file in project with class
import matplotlib.cm as cm

source_file_dem = 'path_to_the_tif_file'

# Set max number of pixel to: 'None' to prevent errors. Its not nice, but works for that case. Big images will load RAM+CPU heavily (like DecompressionBomb)
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None # first we set no limit to open
img = Image.open(source_file_dem)

# get aspect ratio of tif file for late plot box-plot-ratio
y_ratio,x_ratio = img.size

# open georeference TIF file
dem = gdal.Open(source_file_dem)
gt  = dem.GetGeoTransform()
dem_array = dem.ReadAsArray()

# create arrays and declare x,y,z variables
lin_x = np.linspace(0,1,dem_array.shape[0],endpoint=False)
lin_y = np.linspace(0,1,dem_array.shape[1],endpoint=False)
y,x = np.meshgrid(lin_y,lin_x)
z = dem_array

# Apply gaussian filter, with sigmas as variables. Higher sigma = more smoothing and more calculations. Downside: min and max values do change due to smoothing
sigma_y =100
sigma_x = 100
sigma = [sigma_y, sigma_x]
z_smoothed = sp.ndimage.gaussian_filter(z, sigma)

# Some min and max and range values coming from gaussian_filter calculations
z_smoothed_min = np.amin(z_smoothed)
z_smoothed_max = np.amax(z_smoothed)
z_range = z_smoothed_max - z_smoothed_min

# Creating figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.azim = -30
ax.elev = 42
ax.set_box_aspect((x_ratio,y_ratio,((x_ratio+y_ratio)/8)))
ax.arrow3D(1,1,z_smoothed_max, -1,0,1, mutation_scale=20, ec ='black', fc='red') #draw arrow to "north" which is not correct north. But with georeferenced sources it should work
surf = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z_smoothed, cmap='terrain', edgecolor='none')
# setting colors for colorbar range
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=surf.cmap, norm=surf.norm)
m.set_array(z_smoothed)
cbar = fig.colorbar(m, shrink=0.5, aspect=20, ticks=[z_smoothed_min, 0, (z_range*0.25+z_smoothed_min), (z_range*0.5+z_smoothed_min), (z_range*0.75+z_smoothed_min), z_smoothed_max])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([f'{z_smoothed_min}', ' ',  f'{(z_range*0.25+z_smoothed_min)}', f'{(z_range*0.5+z_smoothed_min)}', f'{(z_range*0.75+z_smoothed_min)}', f'{z_smoothed_max}'])
plt.xticks([])  # disabling xticks by Setting xticks to an empty list
plt.yticks([])  # disabling yticks by setting yticks to an empty list
# draw flat rectangle at z = 0 to indicate where mean sea level is in 3d
x_rectangle = [0,1,1,0]
y_rectangle = [0,0,1,1]
z_rectangle = [0,0,0,0]
verts = [list(zip(x_rectangle,y_rectangle,z_rectangle))]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, alpha=0.5))
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Class 3D Arrow (taken from here: https://gist.github.com/WetHat/1d6cd0f7309535311a539b42cccca89c )

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d import proj_transform


class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):

def __init__(self, x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__((0, 0), (0, 0), *args, **kwargs)
    self._xyz = (x, y, z)
    self._dxdydz = (dx, dy, dz)

def draw(self, renderer):
    x1, y1, z1 = self._xyz
    dx, dy, dz = self._dxdydz
    x2, y2, z2 = (x1 + dx, y1 + dy, z1 + dz)

    xs, ys, zs = proj_transform((x1, x2), (y1, y2), (z1, z2), self.axes.M)
    self.set_positions((xs[0], ys[0]), (xs[1], ys[1]))
    super().draw(renderer)

def do_3d_projection(self, renderer=None):
    x1, y1, z1 = self._xyz
    dx, dy, dz = self._dxdydz
    x2, y2, z2 = (x1 + dx, y1 + dy, z1 + dz)

    xs, ys, zs = proj_transform((x1, x2), (y1, y2), (z1, z2), self.axes.M)
    self.set_positions((xs[0], ys[0]), (xs[1], ys[1]))

    return np.min(zs)

def _arrow3D(ax, x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Add an 3d arrow to an `Axes3D` instance.'''

    arrow = Arrow3D(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, *args, **kwargs)
    ax.add_artist(arrow)

setattr(Axes3D, 'arrow3D', _arrow3D)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make a 2D numpy array from the data, you can apply a convolution to it. Look into OpenCV; it has functions for blurring and such.

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for your answer and hints.
With that hints i was able to scramble something together. Ill write an answer for code and pictures so far.